# Como alinhar um checkbox ao lado de uma label?

Tags: html5, checkbox, label, css

Gostaria de alinhar a minha label com o checkbox usando CSS, de modo que a label não fique em baixo do checkbox. Segue um print de como eu gostaria que ficasse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu está ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}




section#principal {
    width: 100%;
}

section#principal .modulo .container {
    height: ;
    padding: 20px;
}

section#principal .modulo .container .canvas {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
}

form ul {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

form li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #161616;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.confirmacoes li {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
}

.confirmacoes input {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Projeto 008</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e0e1b97932.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>                        
 
 <section id="principal">
    
     <div class="modulo">
          
        <div class="container">
            <div class="canvas">
                
                <form action="">                     
                                      
                    <h2>Anythings</h2>
                    <ul class="confirmacoes">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <label>Güncelleme ve yenilikleri mail olarak almak istiyorum.</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id nisl eget nunc molestie maximus.</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                                       
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
     </div>
     
 </section>
                   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso é bem chatinho de fazer... O mais fácil é declarar uma div pro box e outra pro texto e alinhar as duas por porcentagem.
Mas muito cuidado na responsividade.

Comment: Se estiver usando o bootstrap, ele faz isso pra você automaticamente.

Comment: Eu ia propor uma resposta, há muita regra para algo simples. Mas a resposta já solucionou o problema, então ok. Só tome cuidado com o uso de flexbox no Internet Explorer. Veja a aba "known issues" [nesse site](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar uma div em volta do input e declarar a li com display flex, exemplo...

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}




section#principal {
    width: 100%;
}

section#principal .modulo .container {
    height: ;
    padding: 20px;
}

section#principal .modulo .container .canvas {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
}

form ul {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
}

form li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #161616;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.confirmacoes li {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
}

.confirmacoes input {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Projeto 008</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e0e1b97932.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>                        
 
 <section id="principal">
    
     <div class="modulo">
          
        <div class="container">
            <div class="canvas">
                
                <form action="">                     
                                      
                    <h2>Anythings</h2>
                    <ul class="confirmacoes">
                        <li>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                            </div>
                            <label>Güncelleme ve yenilikleri mail olarak almak istiyorum.</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                            </div>
                            <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id nisl eget nunc molestie maximus.</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                                       
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
     </div>
     
 </section>
                   
</body>
</html>
```

Mas fique atento a propriedade flex, pois não é uma especificação adotada por todos os browsers

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Valeu, Felipe. :)

Answer (score 1):

Para estilização de páginas existe vários *frameworks* *front-end* que te auxiliaram na produtividade. Posso afirmar que um dos principais neste aspecto é o [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

No seu código `html`, basta adicionar a tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Que com base na dúvida da tarefa o *bootstrap* já te oferece uma solução [Inline checkboxes and radios](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline-checkboxes-and-radios).

Comment: Importar um framework só para corrigir um alinhamento?

Comment: Não. Adicionar um _framework_ para ganhar em produtividade. Dê uma lida na documentação e veja o quanto ela pode te ajudar em programar em menos tempo. Sem falar que qualquer emprego hoje em dia pede conhecimento em _framworks_, tanto _front_, quando _back_. Enfim, profissionalmente falando, será um conhecimento que agreda valor no seu currículo.

Comment: Olá Djalma, não leve a mal, mas se a pessoa usar no minimo 50% do FW ok é considerado "produtivo", se ela tem uma coisa pronta e só vai importar o bootstrap para alinhar uma coisa é usar bem menos de 5%, ou seja é o mesmo que vc comprar um canhão inteiro só pra matar formigas, a não ser  que ele refatore todo o site e faça um bom uso do Bootstrap, caso contrário creio ser um grande exagero. Novamente peço que não leve a mal ;)

Comment: Concordo com o seu ponto de vista @guilherme. Meu pensamento em usar o _FW_ não foi a curto prazo como proposto na pergunta. Vocês está certo.